# How to publish a subcomponent's property in a compound component?

Tags: delphi, components

In a compound component derived from `TPanel` I'm trying to publish a property whose only pourpose is that to sets and gets a linkage property of a subcomponent. Each time I add my compound component to a form, an access violation is raised:

> Access violation at address 12612D86 in module 'MyRuntimePackage.bpl'. Read of address 00000080.

I've prepared a simplified example using a `TLabel` and its `PopupMenu` property but I still have the same problem when placing the compound component on a form/frame.

**Runtime package:**

```
uses
  StdCtrls, Menus, ExtCtrls, Classes;

type
  TTestCompoundComponent = class(TPanel)
  private
    FSubCmp : TLabel;
    function    GetLabelPopupMenu() : TPopupMenu;
    procedure   SetLabelPopupMenu(AValue : TPopupMenu);
  protected
    procedure   Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner : TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy(); override;
  published
    property    LabelPopupMenu : TPopupMenu read GetLabelPopupMenu write SetLabelPopupMenu;
  end;

...

function    TTestCompoundComponent.GetLabelPopupMenu() : TPopupMenu;
begin
  Result := FSubCmp.PopupMenu;
end;

procedure   TTestCompoundComponent.SetLabelPopupMenu(AValue : TPopupMenu);
begin
  if(GetLabelPopupMenu() <> AValue) then
  begin
    if(GetLabelPopupMenu() <> nil)
    then GetLabelPopupMenu().RemoveFreeNotification(Self);

    FSubCmp.PopupMenu := AValue;

    if(GetLabelPopupMenu() <> nil)
    then GetLabelPopupMenu().FreeNotification(Self);
  end;
end;

procedure   TTestCompoundComponent.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin      
  inherited;
  if((AComponent = GetLabelPopupMenu()) AND (Operation = opRemove))
  then SetLabelPopupMenu(nil);
end;

constructor TTestCompoundComponent.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FSubCmp := TLabel.Create(nil);
  FSubCmp.Parent := Self;
end;

destructor TTestCompoundComponent.Destroy();
begin
  FSubCmp.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

**Designtime package:**

```
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('MyTestCompoundComponent', [TTestCompoundComponent]);
end;
```

Comment: You forgot to call inherited in the Notification method

Comment: @kobik: You're right, thank you! I've updated the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@kobik's answer explains the root cause of the AV (accessing the `FSubCmp.PopupMenu` property before `FSubCmp` is created).  However, your entire component code is overly complicated for what you are trying to achieve.

You should be setting your component as the `TLabel`'s `Owner`, then you can remove your destructor completely.  And you should also be calling `FSubCmp.SetSubComponent(True)` in your constructor (especially if you ever intend to expose the `TLabel` in the Object Inspector at a later time, so the user can customize its properties at design-time):

```
constructor TTestCompoundComponent.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FSubCmp := TLabel.Create(Self);
  FSubCmp.SetSubComponent(True);
  FSubCmp.Parent := Self;
end;
```

Your `Notification()` method should be setting `FSubCmp.PopupMenu := nil` directly in response to `opRemove`, instead of calling `SetLabelPopupMenu(nil)`.  You already know the `PopupMenu` is assigned and that it is in progress of being destroyed, so the extra code to retrieve the `PopupMenu` (repeatedly), check it for `nil`, and call `RemoveFreeNotification()`, is all overkill for an `opRemove` operation:

```
procedure TTestCompoundComponent.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin      
  inherited;
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent = LabelPopupMenu) then
    FSubCmp.PopupMenu := nil;
end;
```

And your `SetLabelPopupMenu()` method is just an eyesore in general, with all those redundant calls to `GetLabelPopupMenu()`.  Call it only one time and store the returned object pointer to a local variable that you can then use as needed:

```
procedure TTestCompoundComponent.SetLabelPopupMenu(AValue: TPopupMenu);
var
  PM: TPopupMenu;
begin
  PM := LabelPopupMenu;

  if (PM <> AValue) then
  begin
    if (PM <> nil) then
      PM.RemoveFreeNotification(Self);

    FSubCmp.PopupMenu := AValue;

    if (AValue <> nil) then
      AValue.FreeNotification(Self);
  end;
end;
```

However, your `Notification()` method is actually *completely redundant* and should be removed altogether.  `TLabel` already calls `FreeNotification()` on its own `PopupMenu` property, and has its own `Notification()` implementation that will set the `PopupMenu` property to `nil` if the `TPopupMenu` object is freed.  You don't need to handle this manually at all.  And so, all of the extra code in `SetLabelPopupMenu()` is redundant and should be removed:

```
procedure TTestCompoundComponent.SetLabelPopupMenu(AValue: TPopupMenu);
begin
  FSubCmp.PopupMenu := AValue;
end;
```

This also means the fix proposed by @kobik is redundant and can be removed as well <sup>1</sup>:

```
function TTestCompoundComponent.GetLabelPopupMenu: TPopupMenu;
begin
  Result := FSubCmp.PopupMenu;
end;
```

<sup>1</sup>: Unless you want to handle the case where a user decides to free your `TLabel` directly (which is foolish, and no one would ever really do that in practice, but it is still technically possible), then you would need `Notification()` to handle that situation (assigning your component as the `TLabel`'s `Owner` will call `FreeNotificatio()` for you):

```
function TTestCompoundComponent.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Opration: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent = FSubCmp) then
    FSubCmp := nil;
end;

function TTestCompoundComponent.GetLabelPopupMenu: TPopupMenu;
begin
  if FSubCmp <> nil then
    Result := FSubCmp.PopupMenu
  else
    Result := nil;
end;
```

That being said, here is a simplified version of your code:

```
uses
  StdCtrls, Menus, ExtCtrls, Classes;

type
  TTestCompoundComponent = class(TPanel)
  private
    FSubCmp: TLabel;
    function GetLabelPopupMenu: TPopupMenu;
    procedure SetLabelPopupMenu(AValue: TPopupMenu);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property LabelPopupMenu: TPopupMenu read GetLabelPopupMenu write SetLabelPopupMenu;
  end;

...

constructor TTestCompoundComponent.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FSubCmp := TLabel.Create(Self);
  FSubCmp.SetSubComponent(True);
  FSubCmp.Parent := Self;
end;

function TTestCompoundComponent.GetLabelPopupMenu: TPopupMenu;
begin
  Result := FSubCmp.PopupMenu;
end;

procedure TTestCompoundComponent.SetLabelPopupMenu(AValue: TPopupMenu);
begin
  FSubCmp.PopupMenu := AValue;
end;
```

Or even just this:

```
uses
  StdCtrls, Menus, ExtCtrls, Classes;

type
  TTestCompoundComponent = class(TPanel)
  private
    FSubCmp: TLabel;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property SubLabel: TLabel read FSubCmp;
  end;

...

constructor TTestCompoundComponent.Create(AOwner : TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FSubCmp := TLabel.Create(Self);
  FSubCmp.SetSubComponent(True);
  FSubCmp.Parent := Self;
end;
```

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer. +1 I completely overlooked the fact that no notification is needed in this case.

Comment: @kobik: you provided the actual answer to the question that was asked (why is the AV happening? Because `FSubCmp` is being accessed before it is created).  I'm just providing some details about how to improve the component's design (which also avoids the AV from happening).

Comment: Great answer! I was doing it completely wrong, I've really appreciated the explanation!

Answer (score 5):

In `GetLabelPopupMenu()`, `FSubCmp` is `nil` when `Notification()` receives an `opInsert` notification during construction before `FSubCmp` has been created.  If `FSubCmp` is `nil`, referring to its `PopupMenu` property will cause the AV.  So, you need to check for that in `GetLabelPopupMenu()`, eg:

```
if FSubCmp = nil then 
  Result := nil
else 
  Result := FSubCmp.PopupMenu;
```

Otherwise, change the order of the `and` logic in `Notification()` to this instead:

```
if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent = GetLabelPopupMenu())
```

If the condition `(Operation = opRemove)` is false, the right side condition will not be evaluated (short-circuit).

Comment: Note that "short circuit evaluation" is dependant on `{$BOOLEVAL}` being set to `OFF` (which it is by default). If it is `ON`, `GetLabelPopupMenu()` will always be called in the `if`, so fixing it to check for `nil` is ultimately the only solution needed.

Comment: Thanks. Since this is he default behavior I did not think to mention it. In any case I wonder why whould anyone in the right mind will set it to ON ever.